# Get calculated values based on the values in different custom values

Tags: stock, inventory, vtigercrm

I am using vtiger 7.2 to create an Inventory management. I have created 4 custom modules called **Purchase**, **Sale**, **Disbursement**, **Returns**. I have created a field called **Available Units** of the product in each module.

Based on the **Product** I select when creating a record, the **Available Units** field should display the stock available. How can I get this value?